# Can't receive DNS queries over TCP

Tags: rust, tcp, dns, udp

When I send DNS query to root server for com name servers over UDP, it's working just fine, but the message is truncated. When I retry over TCP, the Root server does not times out.

```rust
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("199.9.14.201:53")
        .unwrap();

    stream.write(&[251, 188, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1])
        .expect("ugh");

    let mut buf: [u8; 1000] = [1; 1000];
    match stream.peek(&mut buf) {
        Ok(..) => {
            println!("{:?}", buf);
        }

        Err(e) => {
            println!("{:?}", e);
        }
    }

    
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: can you add more information? what is the message that you receive using UDP? and using TCP?

Comment: Any specific reasons, besides learning, not to use a DNS library in your language? There are lots of subtleties in DNS, that yield to either malfunction or security vulnerability. Hence you should rely on trusted libraries instead of trying to do things on your own. Even if you end up writing things yourself, any good library can take a stream of bytes as if received over network and decode it, which could help you see if there are problems in your payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  [RFC 1035 section 4.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-4.2.2):

> Messages sent over TCP connections use server port 53 (decimal).  The
> **message is prefixed with a two byte length field which gives the message length**, excluding the two byte length field.  This length
> field allows the low-level processing to assemble a complete message
> before beginning to parse it.

I looks like your code does not include the required message length. Thus the first two bytes of your message are treated as length which describe a length much larger than what you has send. Therefore the server is waiting for more data.